# Payment gateway integration in java

Tags: java, payment-gateway

I want to integrate a payment gateway in java project.I want some knowledge on payment gateway and its types etc. Can any body give me some idea on this.

Comment: What payment gateway?

Comment: check out J2pay https://github.com/tranxactive/J2PAY

Answer (score 2):

Check for Authorize.Net api for JAVA, It's having several integration method that you can implement in your JAVA Project.

All you need is Authorize.Net SDK, Visit http://developer.authorize.net/downloads/ to download SDK

For Sample Codes Visit http://developer.authorize.net/downloads/samplecode/

You can also check with

- PayPal
- MoneyBookers
- WorldPay